# Wordpress Rewrite Rule API

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm gone crazy with Wordpress rewrite API.
I have:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );  
function add_rewrite_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'type/([^/]+)/?',  
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',  
        'top');
}
```

But when I go on `www.mysite.com/type/article-name`, I'am redirected to `www.mysite.com/2010/01/10/article-name`
(the date is an example), that is the default permalink structure.
How can I prevent this redirect? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I figured it out.The right code is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );  
function add_rewrite_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'l-imbuto/([^/]+)/?$',  
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]',  
        'top');
}
```

I changed the parameter 'pagename' in 'name' and added '/?$' in regex.

`the_permalink();` function display however the 'standard' permalink structure but, It's a minor issue.

Comment: Does the rule need the leading slash?

Comment: It has to be optional

Comment: I'm guessing the regex is incorrect. I will test

Comment: I can't see what the problem is. I'm guessing `$pagename` is not used because your URL is NOT a permalink.

Comment: I think that passing "pagename" parameter is the only way to reach a post by slug.

Comment: I managed to get it solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right code is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );  
function add_rewrite_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'l-imbuto/([^/]+)/?$',  
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]',  
        'top');
}
```

I changed the parameter 'pagename' in 'name' and added '/?$' in regex.

`the_permalink();` function display however the 'standard' permalink structure but, It's a minor issue.